# still invoked toString in invoke methode

Tags: java, reflection, proxy, cglib

I have problem with use of CGLib. I have defined a MethodInterceptor, but when
I call `method.getName()` in the intercept method I get only the result from the `toString()` method ... Why? I don't understand that, because I never call the `toString()` method directly

```
public Object intercept(Object o, Method method, Object[] objects, MethodProxy methodProxy) throws Throwable {
      ....
      method.getName();
      return something;
}
```

when i call method on proxy object i get toString but i call different method.
Thx for every idea.

---UPDATE----
Creating Enhancer:

```
Enhancer enhancer = new Enhancer();
enhancer.setCallback(new GetMethodsInterceptor());
enhancer.setSuperclass(Book.class);
```

I use proxy object

```
 ((Book)enhancer.create()).getValue();
```

where GetMethodsInterceptor() is

```
public class `GetMethodsInterceptor` implements MethodInterceptor {

    public Object intercept(Object o, Method method, Object[] objects, MethodProxy methodProxy) throws Throwable {
        return method.getName();
    }
}
```

Comment: You appear to be calling `method.getName()` but are not doing anything with the String returned. Just calling this method accomplishes nothing, but instead you need to do something with the String object that it produces, either by printing it out, or assigning it to a variable.

Comment: yes i try to return method.getName() and value is still toString .

Comment: Show it -- show real code and real results please.

Comment: ok i try to update my question

Comment: What is the value of the variable 'method' ? Can it possibly be that it is the 'toString' method of some class, and therefore `method.getName()` will return `toString`.